# XCode 6.3.2 Application Load Issue

Tags: xcode6

i m using XCode 6.3.2 OX Version 10.10.3

The session's status is FAILED and the error description is failed to open ssh session (16)

error itms-90022 missing required icon file. 120X120px
error itms-90023 missing required icon file. 76X76px
error itms-90023 missing required icon file. 152X152px

i my resource/icon folder abouve three icons are exists. but application loader showing these error.

how can i solve it.

Regard's 
Shahid Mahmood Khawaja

Comment: you also need to have your icon files in the copy bundle resources ( click on the name of your project -> build phases -> copy bundle ressources ) and make sure your icons are there , good luck

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to solve it
You need too have the correct name of the icon files
try to create your icons by this [web site](http://ticons.fokkezb.nl)

or only change the name of icons to

appicon-76@2x.png
and
appicon-60@2x.png

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem in Xcode 7.

[image]

When I check the Apple official documentation for the app icon:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

I checked very icon and the exactly size,I have set all we can set the icon,and then clean the project and rebuild it,archive it for app store,I have solved this problem at last.